# twitter callback for follower count

Tags: jquery, twitter

```
$(function()
{
    // Get Number of Twitter Followers From Twitter.com
    twitterusername = 'hputtick';

    $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/'+twitterusername+'.json?callback=?',
    function(data)
    {
        $('.twitflw').append('' + data.followers_count + 'followers');
    });
})
```

How can i get this code so that I am left with

```
$('.twitflw').append(post)
```

At the moment the follow count isn't showing at all on the ipad or nexus.

Comment: I entered it in my console and it worked: 576 followers.

Comment: it works, but Its not showing on the tablet. really weird :/